# Install R package with specific version AND tests

Tags: r, installation, devtools, r-package, testthat

I would like to run the package-internal tests with `testthat::test_package('httr')` on a specific version of a package.
Is there a way to install a R package (e.g. from CRAN) with a specific version AND it's tests?

I know there is
`install.packages("httr", INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests")`
to install the tests for the given package (without any option to specify a specific package version).

And there is
`devtools::install_version("httr", version = "1.4.1")` or `renv::install("httr@1.4.1")`
to install a specific version for a package (without the possibility to specify e.g. the INSTALL_opts).

I don't see any way to combine the specification of the package version and the `--install-tests` option.
Any help would be appreciated!

Note: The package "httr" was just used as a placeholder here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`renv` provides a small extension where these options can be set via the `INSTALL_opts` R option. So, for example, the following should work with `renv 0.14.0`:

```
# set options for renv
options(INSTALL_opts.httr = "--install-tests")

# use 'rebuild = true', in case an older version
# of the package without tests is cached
renv::install("httr@1.4.1", rebuild = TRUE)
```

If you wanted these options to apply to all package to be installed, you could instead use:

```
options(INSTALL_opts = "--install-tests")
```

(`renv` supports setting these via options mainly so that package installation via `renv::restore()` can be configured more ergonomically on a per-package basis.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware that the package name can be added to the options so that the option only applies to a single package!
Additionally, I was not aware of the `rebuild=TRUE` option. Thanks!